# MediaPlayer is not working with local files

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play audio from `listview`. I have fetched all the audio files into `listView`. On `itemClick` event of `listview` the song will be played.

The problem occurs when I am using this:

```
MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer.create(this,myFile);
mp.start();
```

This will work for the first time. When I clicked on the second song on the `listView` the first is continued.

I know that `Create()` will create another instance of MediaPlayer. I have declared it as static and it still is creating other instances or I don't know what it is doing.

I have tried with `mp.setDataSource(context,myUri);` but that would causing the error on `reset()` and `stop()`.

Here is my code. Can anyone guide me what it is that I'm doing wrong?

```
public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    View myView;
    private String[] theNamesOfFiles;
    Intent i = new Intent();
    public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

        final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Ringtones");
        File[] filelist = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return !pathname.isHidden();
            }
        });
        theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
            theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();

        }

        ListView listview = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.RecordingList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listviewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theNamesOfFiles
        );
        listview.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Uri myUri=  Uri.parse(dir+"/"+theNamesOfFiles[position]);
                mp.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),myUri);
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                }
                mp.start();
            }

        });

        return myView;
    }


}
```

The Logcat Showing follwing

> E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
>
> E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change listview's onclicklistner code as below:

```
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(dir + "/" + theNamesOfFiles[position]);
            try {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, myUri);
                mp.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

also in oncreate put this listner code before listview's onclicklistner

```
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();
            else
                mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah i missed the oncreate method thnks

Comment: Is your problem solved? if yes, using my answer than please mark it as accepted else let us know the issue.